# SSR error in React 18: "This root received an early update, before anything was able hydrate. Switched the entire root to client rendering."

Tags: server-side-rendering, react-18

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out. Here is my current setup in index.js. I don't understand why I get the error mentioned above.

```
    import React from "react";
    import "normalize.css";
    import "./index.css";
    import App from "./App";
    import {store} from './store';
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import {hydrateRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
    import {HelmetProvider} from 'react-helmet-async';
    const container = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = hydrateRoot(container, <App/>);
    root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HelmetProvider>
            <App tab="home" />
        </HelmetProvider>
    </Provider>);
```

I tried this setup, but it just gave me many more errors:

```
    import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    const container = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = hydrateRoot(container, 
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HelmetProvider>
            <App />
        </HelmetProvider>
     </Provider>);
```

errors:
1.Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
2.Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
3.An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in .
4.Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
5.There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.